# How to disable hot reload in create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, firefox, webpack, create-react-app

How to disable hot reload in create-react-app and reload browser only manually? Currently it reloads after every change in project.
I'm using Firefox and tried to block request `localhost:3000/sockjs-node/*` how is suggested [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2519) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blocking `localhost:3000/sockjs-node/*` only blocks requests for the `/sockjs-node/` path (note the trailing `/`) and all subpaths. This will not block requests made to `localhost:3000/sockjs-node`, which is what CRA uses for hot reloading. Change your request blocking filter to `localhost:3000/sockjs-node`.

Comment: Hmm looks like in Chromium 89 it's no longer possible to block Websocket requests at all :(

Comment: For me blocking `http://localhost:3000/sockjs-node*` in firefox dev tools works.

Comment: For CRA 5+, the URL has changed: "ws://localhost:3000/ws"