# How to disable hot-loading in React

Tags: reactjs

When I change my React app's `public` folder content, my React app automatically reloads. How do you disable this feature?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64479125/how-to-disable-hot-reload-in-create-react-app)'s answer, but it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a feature they allow you to edit unfortunately.

What you can do is do it by your browser. That answer you linked to is a couple years old, so the URL is incorrect. Look up how to do this for your browser, but you want to block a URL with it. The URL you want to block is `http://localhost:<port>/*.hot-update.js`.

By default CRA runs on port 3000, so insert that if you haven't changed anything.

To disable updates when changing assets in `public/`, append the following to your `index.html`:

```
<script>
  {
    var WS = window.WebSocket;
    function DevWebSocket(s) {
      if (s === "ws://localhost:3000/sockjs-node") {
        console.info("[DEV NOTICE] Live Reload Has Been Disabled");
        return {};
      } else {
        // Pass through other usage of sockets
        return new WS(s);
      }
    }
    window.WebSocket = DevWebSocket;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: when I add or delete file inside the public folder that time also react-app is loaded

Comment: @ShatishDesai Ah, that's a bit different. See my updated reply.

Comment: it stopped live loading also. How to disable just hot-loading

Comment: Hot loading is what I said first. Blocking the URL. When you add or delete files inside `public/` that's live loading which you just asked me how to stop?

Comment: Yes, that is my Question. sorry for the Improper question

Comment: live loading disable for just public folder change. it is possible

Comment: Not without customizing the webpack config, no.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229926/discussion-between-shatish-desai-and-rschristian).